# ffmpeg with Quick Sync Video (qsv) gets stuck

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, intel, transcoding

I've compiled `ffmpeg` in an Arch Linux distribution with support to [Intel Quick Sync Video](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync). But `ffmpeg` gets stuck when I try to run it:

```
$ ffmpeg -debug -hwaccel qsv -qsv_device /dev/dri/renderD128 -c:v h264_qsv -i test_video.mp4 -c:v hevc_qsv output.mp4

ffmpeg version N-109562-g0431f9805e Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 12.2.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-cflags=-I/opt/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/opt/cuda/lib64 --enable-lto --disable-rpath --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-stripping --enable-gray --enable-alsa --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-gcrypt --enable-gmp --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-ladspa --enable-lcms2 --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcelt --enable-libcdio --enable-libcodec2 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libdavs2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libflite --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libglslang --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-libilbc --enable-libjack --enable-libjxl --enable-libklvanc --enable-libkvazaar --enable-liblensfun --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-libopencv --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --disable-libopenvino --enable-libopus --enable-libplacebo --enable-libpulse --enable-librabbitmq --enable-librav1e --enable-librist --enable-librsvg --enable-librubberband --enable-librtmp --enable-libshine --enable-libsmbclient --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libsvthevc --enable-libsvtvp9 --disable-libtensorflow --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --disable-libtls --enable-libtwolame --enable-libuavs3d --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxavs2 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxcb-shm --enable-libxcb-xfixes --enable-libxcb-shape --enable-libxvid --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-lv2 --enable-lzma --enable-decklink --disable-mbedtls --enable-libmysofa --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --disable-openssl --enable-pocketsphinx --enable-sndio --enable-sdl2 --enable-vapoursynth --enable-vulkan --enable-xlib --enable-zlib --enable-amf --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-libdrm --enable-libvpl --enable-libnpp --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-rkmpp --enable-v4l2-m2m --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau
  libavutil      57. 43.100 / 57. 43.100
  libavcodec     59. 56.100 / 59. 56.100
  libavformat    59. 34.102 / 59. 34.102
  libavdevice    59.  8.101 / 59.  8.101
  libavfilter     8. 53.100 /  8. 53.100
  libswscale      6.  8.112 /  6.  8.112
  libswresample   4.  9.100 /  4.  9.100
  libpostproc    56.  7.100 / 56.  7.100
 matched as AVOption 'debug' with argument '-hwaccel'.
Reading option 'qsv' ... matched as output url.
Reading option '-qsv_device' ... matched as option 'qsv_device' (set QSV hardware device (DirectX adapter index, DRM path or X11 display name)) with argument '/dev/dri/renderD128'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'h264_qsv'.
Reading option '-i' ... matched as input url with argument 'test_video.mp4'.
Reading option '-c:v' ... matched as option 'c' (codec name) with argument 'hevc_qsv'.
Reading option 'output.mp4' ... matched as output url.
Finished splitting the commandline.
Parsing a group of options: global .
Applying option qsv_device (set QSV hardware device (DirectX adapter index, DRM path or X11 display name)) with argument /dev/dri/renderD128.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] libva: VA-API version 1.17.0
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] libva: User requested driver 'iHD'
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] libva: Trying to open /usr/lib/dri/iHD_drv_video.so
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] libva: Found init function __vaDriverInit_1_16
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] libva: va_openDriver() returns 0
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Initialised VAAPI connection: version 1.17
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x41524742 -> bgra.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x42475241 -> argb.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x41424752 -> rgba.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x52474241 -> abgr.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x58524742 -> bgr0.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x42475258 -> 0rgb.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x58424752 -> rgb0.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x52474258 -> 0bgr.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30335241 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30334241 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30335258 -> x2rgb10le.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30334258 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x36314752 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x50424752 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x50524742 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x56555941 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30303859 -> gray.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x3231564e -> nv12.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x3132564e -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x32595559 -> yuyv422.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x59565955 -> uyvy422.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x32315659 -> yuv420p.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30323449 -> yuv420p.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x50313134 -> yuv411p.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x48323234 -> yuv422p.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x56323234 -> yuv440p.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x50343434 -> yuv444p.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x33434d49 -> unknown.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Format 0x30313050 -> p010le.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] VAAPI driver: Intel iHD driver for Intel(R) Gen Graphics - 22.6.4 ().
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517ee40] Driver not found in known nonstandard list, using standard behaviour.
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0x5590d517e940] Use Intel(R) oneVPL to create MFX session, API version is 2.6, the required implementation version is 1.3
```

CPU starts being used intensively and then nothing happens.
Does anybody have any clue on it?

I have an Intel i7-8550U (8th gen Kaby Lake) processor with 4 cores (8 threads).

I have also used these options to `ffmpeg`, getting the same results:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel debug -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -i test_video.mp4 -vf 'format=qsv,hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64' -c:v hevc_qsv -f mp4 output.mp4
```

With VAAPI, transcoding runs flowlessly:

```
ffmpeg -init_hw_device vaapi=intel:/dev/dri/renderD128 -hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi -hwaccel_device intel -filter_hw_device intel -i test_video.mp4 -c:v hevc_vaapi -f mp4 output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My experience with ffmpeg's MFX and OneVPL integrations over the years show consistent success across multiple QSV-capable platforms using a [hybrid strategy](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Hardware/QuickSync#Hybridtranscode).

Here,we initialize a VAAPI's HWContext,followed by deriving a qsv device/instance for encoding via [hwmap](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#hwmap), rather than calling up QSV's HWContext directly. Using `hwmap` also allows further runtime flexibility as regards mapping modes, with the option to request zero-copy emulation via the `direct` mapping mode.

See the solution below,adapted from your command-line above:

```bash
ffmpeg -init_hw_device vaapi=intel:/dev/dri/renderD128 \
-hwaccel vaapi -hwaccel_output_format vaapi \
-hwaccel_device intel -filter_hw_device intel \
-i test_video.mp4 \
-vf 'scale_vaapi,hwmap=derive_device=qsv,format=qsv' \
-c:v hevc_qsv -f mp4 output.mp4
```

You can view the respective codec wrapper options via:

```bash
ffmpeg -h encoder=hevc_qsv
```

**Sample output:**

```bash
Encoder hevc_qsv [HEVC (Intel Quick Sync Video acceleration)]:
    General capabilities: delay hybrid 
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: qsv qsv qsv 
    Supported pixel formats: nv12 p010le p012le yuyv422 y210le qsv bgra x2rgb10le vuyx xv30le
hevc_qsv encoder AVOptions:
  -async_depth       <int>        E..V....... Maximum processing parallelism (from 1 to INT_MAX) (default 4)
  -preset            <int>        E..V....... (from 0 to 7) (default 0)
     veryfast        7            E..V.......
     faster          6            E..V.......
     fast            5            E..V.......
     medium          4            E..V.......
     slow            3            E..V.......
     slower          2            E..V.......
     veryslow        1            E..V.......
  -forced_idr        <boolean>    E..V....... Forcing I frames as IDR frames (default false)
  -low_power         <boolean>    E..V....... enable low power mode(experimental: many limitations by mfx version, BRC modes, etc.) (default auto)
  -rdo               <int>        E..V....... Enable rate distortion optimization (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -max_frame_size    <int>        E..V....... Maximum encoded frame size in bytes (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  -max_frame_size_i  <int>        E..V....... Maximum encoded I frame size in bytes (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  -max_frame_size_p  <int>        E..V....... Maximum encoded P frame size in bytes (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  -max_slice_size    <int>        E..V....... Maximum encoded slice size in bytes (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default -1)
  -mbbrc             <int>        E..V....... MB level bitrate control (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -extbrc            <int>        E..V....... Extended bitrate control (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -p_strategy        <int>        E..V....... Enable P-pyramid: 0-default 1-simple 2-pyramid(bf need to be set to 0). (from 0 to 2) (default 0)
  -b_strategy        <int>        E..V....... Strategy to choose between I/P/B-frames (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -dblk_idc          <int>        E..V....... This option disable deblocking. It has value in range 0~2. (from 0 to 2) (default 0)
  -low_delay_brc     <boolean>    E..V....... Allow to strictly obey avg frame size (default auto)
  -max_qp_i          <int>        E..V....... Maximum video quantizer scale for I frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -min_qp_i          <int>        E..V....... Minimum video quantizer scale for I frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -max_qp_p          <int>        E..V....... Maximum video quantizer scale for P frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -min_qp_p          <int>        E..V....... Minimum video quantizer scale for P frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -max_qp_b          <int>        E..V....... Maximum video quantizer scale for B frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -min_qp_b          <int>        E..V....... Minimum video quantizer scale for B frame (from -1 to 51) (default -1)
  -adaptive_i        <int>        E..V....... Adaptive I-frame placement (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -adaptive_b        <int>        E..V....... Adaptive B-frame placement (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -scenario          <int>        E..V....... A hint to encoder about the scenario for the encoding session (from 0 to 8) (default unknown)
     unknown         0            E..V.......
     displayremoting 1            E..V.......
     videoconference 2            E..V.......
     archive         3            E..V.......
     livestreaming   4            E..V.......
     cameracapture   5            E..V.......
     videosurveillance 6            E..V.......
     gamestreaming   7            E..V.......
     remotegaming    8            E..V.......
  -avbr_accuracy     <int>        E..V....... Accuracy of the AVBR ratecontrol (unit of tenth of percent) (from 0 to 65535) (default 0)
  -avbr_convergence  <int>        E..V....... Convergence of the AVBR ratecontrol (unit of 100 frames) (from 0 to 65535) (default 0)
  -skip_frame        <int>        E..V....... Allow frame skipping (from 0 to 3) (default no_skip)
     no_skip         0            E..V....... Frame skipping is disabled
     insert_dummy    1            E..V....... Encoder inserts into bitstream frame where all macroblocks are encoded as skipped
     insert_nothing  2            E..V....... Encoder inserts nothing into bitstream
     brc_only        3            E..V....... skip_frame metadata indicates the number of missed frames before the current frame
  -idr_interval      <int>        E..V....... Distance (in I-frames) between IDR frames (from -1 to INT_MAX) (default 0)
     begin_only      -1           E..V....... Output an IDR-frame only at the beginning of the stream
  -load_plugin       <int>        E..V....... A user plugin to load in an internal session (from 0 to 2) (default hevc_hw)
     none            0            E..V.......
     hevc_sw         1            E..V.......
     hevc_hw         2            E..V.......
  -load_plugins      <string>     E..V....... A :-separate list of hexadecimal plugin UIDs to load in an internal session (default "")
  -look_ahead_depth  <int>        E..V....... Depth of look ahead in number frames, available when extbrc option is enabled (from 0 to 100) (default 0)
  -profile           <int>        E..V....... (from 0 to INT_MAX) (default unknown)
     unknown         0            E..V.......
     main            1            E..V.......
     main10          2            E..V.......
     mainsp          3            E..V.......
     rext            4            E..V.......
     scc             9            E..V.......
  -tier              <int>        E..V....... Set the encoding tier (only level >= 4 can support high tier) (from 0 to 256) (default high)
     main            0            E..V.......
     high            256          E..V.......
  -gpb               <boolean>    E..V....... 1: GPB (generalized P/B frame); 0: regular P frame (default true)
  -tile_cols         <int>        E..V....... Number of columns for tiled encoding (from 0 to 65535) (default 0)
  -tile_rows         <int>        E..V....... Number of rows for tiled encoding (from 0 to 65535) (default 0)
  -recovery_point_sei <int>        E..V....... Insert recovery point SEI messages (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -aud               <boolean>    E..V....... Insert the Access Unit Delimiter NAL (default false)
  -pic_timing_sei    <boolean>    E..V....... Insert picture timing SEI with pic_struct_syntax element (default true)
  -transform_skip    <int>        E..V....... Turn this option ON to enable transformskip (from -1 to 1) (default -1)
  -int_ref_type      <int>        E..V....... Intra refresh type. B frames should be set to 0 (from -1 to 65535) (default -1)
     none            0            E..V.......
     vertical        1            E..V.......
     horizontal      2            E..V.......
     slice           3            E..V.......
  -int_ref_cycle_size <int>        E..V....... Number of frames in the intra refresh cycle (from -1 to 65535) (default -1)
  -int_ref_qp_delta  <int>        E..V....... QP difference for the refresh MBs (from -32768 to 32767) (default -32768)
  -int_ref_cycle_dist <int>        E..V....... Distance between the beginnings of the intra-refresh cycles in frames (from -1 to 32767) (default -1)
```

And for the filter(s) used:

```bash
ffmpeg -h filter=scale_vaapi
```

**Sample output:**

```bash
Filter scale_vaapi
  Scale to/from VAAPI surfaces.
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
scale_vaapi AVOptions:
   w                 <string>     ..FV....... Output video width (default "iw")
   h                 <string>     ..FV....... Output video height (default "ih")
   format            <string>     ..FV....... Output video format (software format of hardware frames)
   mode              <int>        ..FV....... Scaling mode (from 0 to 768) (default hq)
     default         0            ..FV....... Use the default (depend on the driver) scaling algorithm
     fast            256          ..FV....... Use fast scaling algorithm
     hq              512          ..FV....... Use high quality scaling algorithm
     nl_anamorphic   768          ..FV....... Use nolinear anamorphic scaling algorithm
   out_color_matrix  <string>     ..FV....... Output colour matrix coefficient set
   out_range         <int>        ..FV....... Output colour range (from 0 to 2) (default 0)
     full            2            ..FV....... Full range
     limited         1            ..FV....... Limited range
     jpeg            2            ..FV....... Full range
     mpeg            1            ..FV....... Limited range
     tv              1            ..FV....... Limited range
     pc              2            ..FV....... Full range
   out_color_primaries <string>     ..FV....... Output colour primaries
   out_color_transfer <string>     ..FV....... Output colour transfer characteristics
   out_chroma_location <string>     ..FV....... Output chroma sample location
   force_original_aspect_ratio <int>        ..FV....... decrease or increase w/h if necessary to keep the original AR (from 0 to 2) (default disable)
     disable         0            ..FV.......
     decrease        1            ..FV.......
     increase        2            ..FV.......
   force_divisible_by <int>        ..FV....... enforce that the output resolution is divisible by a defined integer when force_original_aspect_ratio is used (from 1 to 256) (default 1)
```

```bash
ffmpeg -h filter=hwmap
```

**Sample output:**

```bash
Filter hwmap
  Map hardware frames
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
hwmap AVOptions:
   mode              <flags>      ..FV....... Frame mapping mode (default read+write)
     read                         ..FV....... Mapping should be readable
     write                        ..FV....... Mapping should be writeable
     overwrite                    ..FV....... Mapping will always overwrite the entire frame
     direct                       ..FV....... Mapping should not involve any copying
   derive_device     <string>     ..FV....... Derive a new device of this type
   reverse           <int>        ..FV....... Map in reverse (create and allocate in the sink) (from 0 to 1) (default 0)
```

**Extra notes:**

Not all rate-control and encoding modes may be available on your platform.
To verify what's supported, cross-verify `vainfo`'s output with the [support matrix](https://github.com/intel/media-driver#supported-platforms) hosted on `intel-media-driver`'s project.

Intel's media delivery project on Github also provides [reference command-lines](https://github.com/intel/media-delivery/blob/master/doc/reference-command-lines.rst) outlining specific fix-ups for performance and quality trade-offs with respect to low-power encoding, rate control method availability, etc. It's a good start to grasp the basics on what may break in production.

Where possible, try to build the [cartwheel-ffmpeg](https://github.com/intel/cartwheel-ffmpeg) branch maintained by Intel for troubleshooting any QSV-related performance issues and likewise, [report any bugs](https://github.com/intel/cartwheel-ffmpeg/issues) you may encounter there.

Comment: Using `ffmpeg-intel-full` Arch Linux package, I could run the original command I was trying to execute. Anyway, I've done some tests. VAAPI is still strangely faster than QSV, according to my measures.I've used

Comment: Using `ffmpeg-intel-full` Arch Linux package, I could run the original command I was trying to execute. Anyway, I've done some tests. VAAPI is still strangely faster than QSV, according to my measures.  
I've used as a input a 640x480, 29.97fps, 1h 04min 45s h264 video. I've got these results:  
VAAPI: speed around 10x, 589.6 kb/s, around 300 FPS, 6min 27s encoding time;  
Your solution: speed around 8.2x, around 250 FPS, 7min 46s encoding time;  
Original command: speed around 8.15x, around 244 FPS, 7min 58s
I'll mark your answer, since you suggested me to use Intel's version of ffmpeg.

Comment: Your results are quite normal, and fall within expectation(s). OneVPL dropped opaque memory support and *some* rate control methods which may explain the performance disparities between VAAPI and QSV on specific FFmpeg builds.